# django-social-auth twitterBackend , always redirected to LOGIN_URL_ERROR

Tags: python, django, twitter, oauth, django-socialauth

I started using django-social-auth which looks great, i want to setup a tiny twitter app and just need the twitter connect. I followed the guidelines and examples.
The twitter connect looks like it's working, i am redirected to twitter authentication but when returning back to my callbackUrl i get
always redirected to the LOGIN_URL_ERROR, i have no error messages. I tried adding django logging still no error is showed. 
The messages module used in the example views gives me: 
    "Sorry but some error made you impossible to login. Please try again"

I am currently testing on localhost so maybe it's the problem, i have setup the twitter app with the url: local.dev:8000 and  callbackUrl: local.dev:8000/filtered 
with a mapping on /etc/hosts

[settings.py](http://pastebin.com/Pwms3CG3)

[social_settings.py](http://pastebin.com/GbYMr7nR)

[views.py](http://pastebin.com/CvvQreP5)

[urls.py](http://pastebin.com/2vpE3AwR)

python2.7, django 1.3, django-social-auth github repo

Comment: You should try testing on the same domain as your application is configured. You can also use a subdomain. An entry in your hosts file should do the trick. For example, you could point `local.yourdomain.com` to `127.0.0.1`.